multiple headers excel loader,langchain , excel chatbot
i am creating question and answer using excel, i am using recursive text splitter.i am able to generate answer for simple excel files but the problem is with the excel file with multiple headers
like](https://i.sstatic.net/gwPEiNlI.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/gwPEiNlI.png)
this is just a small snip of the excel file. I am using OpenAI model, tried unstructuredexcelloader, but no luck
tried unstructuredexcelloader, unstrucuredfileloader, tried to use pandas and on the go loading to unstructuredexcelloader
